# How to split changes on my PR into two separate PR's without losing comments?

Tags: github, azure-devops, version-control, git-merge

I made sweeping changes to 2 projects (call it Project A and B) in my team's repository in this PR *. After getting through testing, review, and getting comments resolved, I found out that a different team is working on conflicting changes to project A on a different PR and those changes need to go to staging first. Now I can't merge my PR because it has changes to A, but my changes to Project B need to be merged ASAP. Now the obvious answer is probably to abandon the PR, do a soft reset and start again with two branches, but my team wants to keep the comment threads on both A and B because they showcase a month of work and important design decisions made by multiple teams during the reviewing process. Is there a way to split my changes to Projects A and B into two separate PR's without losing all the comments?

My current solution is branch a new branch off the current one, manually undo my changes to Project A from the branch, push, and leave the comments to A dangling (I think there will be some comment view that the file reference is deleted), merge. Then create a new PR of the newest branch, copy and paste each of the 50+ dangling comments over to their respective files, resolve all, and merge. This is obviously not great because I lose some context and it will take hours. Other solutions I've seen on here will delete all existing comments altogether and I can't have that.

*Yes, I definitely shouldn't have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution for this.

I would suggest to use [Azure DevOps APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0), and even that isn’t a walk in the park.

### Modus operandi

Choose your language, PowerShell, js, c#, etc and start exploring. Below a suggestion where to start:

1. Start with getting the original PR using the [getbyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) api
2. Since you mention the comments are the most import part, the next thing is to retrieving [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-thread-comments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) with thread comments API.
3. Optional: Per comment iterate through the thread with the next [get api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#gitpullrequestcommentthread), because the docs state: Represents a comment which is one of potentially many in a comment thread.
4. From this point, retrieve more info you need or start building the copy of the PR with, [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) PR and adding comments and other part you need to reuse.

Again, this is not easy and maybe retrieving and saving this in another format already helps you.

I did tried to find a solution for you online, but did find it (yet). Found other handy stuff like this [quick and dirty js script to search through comments](https://gist.github.com/hashtagchris/1862d37adaef521296d521371f20cd35).